# Trying to find the jar in which com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser class is present

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I am trying to form a SOAP Envelope request from a WSDL and came across a solution in the following link http://www.membrane-soa.org/soa-model-doc/1.4/java-api/create-soap-request-template.htm. But I am unable find the jar in which the following class is present com.predic8.wsdl.WSDLParser. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it from the same site (like with example of usage).

Just go to "downloads" at the top and download "Membrane SOA Model - Java API for WSDL and XML Schema" - it will contain soa-model-core-1.4.1.4.jar with all these classes.

Comment: Is there any repository in which this jar presents?

Comment: Here is link to POM which contains repository address - you can also use it as an example https://github.com/membrane/soa-model/blob/master/distribution/pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

A Google search for the classname resulted in the following GitHub project:

https://github.com/membrane/soa-model